# How to add text right next to an Image in Google Colab using HTML?

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, markdown, google-colaboratory

I am trying to have some text right next to an image in a Google Colab Markdown cell using HTML, but haven't been able to do so.

I took some reference from [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/html/text-next-to-image-html/) but it didn't work for me. The code is this,

```
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
<img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="img"/>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
<p>
Here goes the text content.
</p>
</div>
```

Output -

[image]

How can I have it so the text is right beside the image, and I can even change the font size?

You can try your answers by entering them in a Mardown Cell of this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16YxbGTf3hrvHJhpapB25jMs5F_W02YZ2?usp=sharing).

Comment: Without changing your html or it possible to restructure it?

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap your content (image, text) in a div. The div i would assign to flex. That it...

#### Update: With inline-style

```html
<div style="display: flex; gap:10px;">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="img"/>
  <p style="font-size: 30px;">
    Here goes the text content.
  </p>
</div>
```

#### Update 2: with using float

```html
<div style="display: inline; float: left">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="img"/>
  <p style="float: right; font-size: 30px;">
    Here goes the text content.
  </p>
</div>
```

#### Using Table

```html
<table>   
  <tr>     
    <td><img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="img"/></td>     
    <td>Txt</td>   
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: This would probably work in normal HTML, but I am writing this inside a Jupyter notebook's mardown cell.

Comment: @Zero ok. i will take a look what that is. thanks for feedback

Comment: @Zero I updated my answer. i chagne it  to inline style...

Comment: Sorry but it still doesn't work. Your answer works on normal HTML, but not in a Jupyter markdown cell.

Comment: @Zero I updated again :-) With float:left and right. Waiting for feedback ;-)

Comment: Still no, sorry. But thanks for answering and constantly updating the answer. Here is a test Colab notebook [click here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16YxbGTf3hrvHJhpapB25jMs5F_W02YZ2?usp=sharing). Try writing the code in a markdown cell and seeing the output.

Comment: @Zero Thank you! i realise i should take the time. In any case, it's an exciting topic. If you need a quick fix, I would use a very pragmatic table.  `<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="img"/></td>
    <td>Txt</td>
  </tr>
</table>`

Comment: This sorta works but is not what am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content: space-between;">

    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="img" />
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <p>
            Here goes the text content.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use flexbox

Comment: This doesn't work. Can you share what the output is for you?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/sQb7KJf/Screenshot-19.png

Comment: That's using normal HTML. I want it inside a Jupyter notebook's markdown cell.